# Random Popups While Automating the Webpage

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

I was attending an interview and he gave me the following scenarios . If I could get an hint as I could not answer the questions.

- Assume that there is an application and popups keep coming up all the time. These are not times, its just random. You never know when they are going to come. How to deal with it?
- Assume that the script you wrote is fine. But due to network issues the objects in the page are really slow to load or the page itself is taking long time. How do you deal with such a scenario?
- Assume that I have 5-6 pages in the application. In all the pages we have certain text fields. In page 1 and Page 5 there is an object which is a text box. I see that what ever whatever identification method (css, xpath, id etc) you take, the values are same. That is duplicates. How do you deal with this scenario?
- What is the basic purpose of "data provider" annotation in TestNG. In genral, what is the purpose of testng annotations?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that the script you wrote is fine. But due to network issues the objects in the page are really slow to load or the page itself is taking long time.

How do you deal with such a scenario. In such situation, You should Wait property of Selenium. Implicit Wait or Explicit wait.

Implicit Wait -- Used for setting Timeout for Webpage loading

```
Driverobject.manage().timeouts().PageLoadtimeOut(units,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Explicit Wait-- Used for setting Timeout for particular

```
Webelement FirefoxDriver f = new FirefoxDriver(); 
WebDriverWait ww = new WebDriverWait(f,Units); 
ww.until(ExpectedConditions.CONDITION);
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer. Thank you very much Anubhav.

Answer (score 0):

For second question, Anubhav has answered it.

For third, even if elements are same for the page1 and page5, they can be differentiated. First, switch to page to, whose text field you want to interact with, and then interact with that text field.

For forth, dataprovider is an annotation in TestNG using which you can do data driven testing and using TestNG annotations, you can manage test execution flow of your tests. For more details of dataprovider and TestNG annotation, please go [here](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html)

Comment: I appreciate your answer. Thank you very much TDHM.

Comment: It says i need +15 Reputation to 'upvote' an answer. i have 3. :( sorry.

Answer (score 0):

For third, If you open 5-6 the pages in different tabs of single browser you will get such a duplication problem. That time only one page is visible to the end user. So we can differentiate that element by visibility and can interact with that element using webdriver

```
List<WebElement> el=driver.findElements(By.xpath("xpath of that text element"));//you can use other than xpath too to identify the elements
    for(int i=0;i<el.size();i++)
    {
        if(el.get(i).isDisplayed())
            el.get(i).sendKeys("text you want to send");//any other action you want to perform
        break;
    }
```